# Trying to understand the total derivative/differential.

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, intuition

I'm asking this question because I'm having problems understanting the definition of differential/total derivative in multivariable calculus, and in order to improve my understanding of it, I want to make sure I have the right intuition behind the definition.

Let $F:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^m$ be a function and $a\in\mathbb{R}^n$. We say that $F$ is differentiable at $a$ iff there exists a linear transformation $L:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^m$ such that

$$\lim_{x\to a}\frac{\|F(x)-(L(x-a)+F(a))\|_m}{\|x-a\|_n}=0.$$

In this case $L$ will be called the differential of $F$ at $a$ (as it is later proven that this linear transformation is unique) and will be denoted $DF_a$. As my proffesor explained, the differential is the *best* linear aproximation there is to $F$ close to $a$. Now, I understand that $G:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^m$ defined as $G(x)=DF_a(x-a)+F(a)$ is moving the graph of the function $DF_a$ ($Gr(DF_a):=\{(x_1,...,x_n,DF_a^1(x_1,...,x_n),...,DF_a^m(x_1,...,x_n))|x_i\in\mathbb{R},i=1,...,n\}$, where each $DF_a^i:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ is the $i$-th component function of $DF_a$), to the point $(a_1,...,a_n,F_1(a_1,...,a_n),...,F_m(a_1,...,a_n))$, and in this sense $G(x)$ approaches $F(x)$ as $x$ goes to $a$. This is where the confusion starts (please correct me in anything if I'm wrong).

How is it justified that $G$ approaches $F$ as $x$ goes to $a$? Is it true that $\lim_{x\to a}\|F(x)-G(x)\|_m=0$? If so, why is that not the definition? How does dividing over something that goes to zero while preserving the existence and value of the limit guarantee that $G$ is the *best* linear approximation? As I've heard before, it is to be understood that $\|F(x)-G(x)\|_m$ goes to zero faster than $\|x-a\|_n$ does, as $x$ approaches $a$, but once again, how is this justified?

I'm sorry if this is too much or if it seems as if I have not worked as much in trying to learn this, but I really have been trying a lot lately and I'm having a hard time in doing so.

Any help is greatly thanked for. Greetings.

Answer (score 3):

> How is it justified that  approaches  as  goes to ?

Well, this is simply because
$$
\lim_{x\to a}G(x)=
\lim_{x\to a}(F(a)+DF_a(x-a))=\lim_{x\to a}F(a)+\lim_{x\to a}DF_a(x-a)
=F(a)+0=F(a)
$$